# quickest way to check a range for valid data points ... avoiding a loop in vba

Tags: vba, loops, memory

Hi I'm wondering what is the quickest (least memory using) way to check a range of data points to see if the points are valid.

Lets say I have a rng = Range("A1:A100"). I want to write something such that

```
If c in rng = "N/A Requesting Data..." Then
     x = false
Else
     Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "refresh" .... etc.    
End if
```

Can i do this without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks `A1:A100` of the `ActiveSheet`. If no cells contain "N/A" as part of their text `RangeLooksGood` is set to True.

```
Sub TestRangeForValidContent()
Dim RangeLooksGood As Boolean

With ActiveSheet
RangeLooksGood = (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1:A100"), "*N/A*") = 0)
End With
If RangeLooksGood Then
     Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "refresh"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good. Please note that I fat-finger my original code and used `CountIf(.Range("A1:A100"), "*N?A*")`. The "?" in "N?A" means "N" followed by any character followed by "A", so something like "Santa Claus" would read as an invalid cell. It should be `CountIf(.Range("A1:A100"), "*N/A*")` as in my edit.